# Primary key inheritance in .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, primary-key

I have a base class `BaseFunction`:

```
public class BaseFunction
    {
        [Key]
        public int BaseFunctionID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a derived class 'ObjectiveFunction`:

```
public class ObjectiveFunction : BaseFunction
    {
        public bool IsMax { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to build a migration, I get the error:
`"The entity type 'ObjectiveFunction' requires a primary key to be defined.`

I was under the assumption the primary key would be defined by the base class `ObjectiveFunction` extends. Am I misunderstanding how to set this up or do I have something else going on (un-synced migrations, for example?)

Comment: First thing I would do is make that BaseFunction class abstract, unless you absolutely need a table representing it

Comment: It could work well in my project.What is the version of your ef core?And what is your dbcontext like?

Comment: @jjxtra making the class abstract fixed the issue. If you submit it as an answer, I'll happily accept it. Thank you for the help

Comment: I added the answer ;)

Comment: I have similar database design for an old .net framework 4.5 project. I am not able to get the relationship defined correctly so that insert/update can work for derived classes. I can read the data after scaffolding existing database and removing inverse properties as they do not exists in the base/derived classes because of similar relationship. Did you get things working after making the base class abstract or you had to do change the hierarchical relationship entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the base class abstract, this will fix things. If it is not abstract then entity framework will assume the base class is a different table and not create the key.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why.